# Simplify the math expression $M=(1-b)^{N}+(N-4)(1-b)^{N-1} b+ \sum^{N}_{i=1} 2^{2i-2} \Delta^2 (1-b)^{N-1}b-(1-2b)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

Can someone help me to further simplify the following expression? Here, $0<b<1$ and we can assume that $b$ is small. $\Delta$ is a constant. Thank you

$M=(1-b)^{N}+(N-4)(1-b)^{N-1} b+ \sum^{N}_{i=1} 2^{2i-2} \Delta^2 (1-b)^{N-1}b-(1-2b)^2$

Comment: I assume if you are told that $0 < b < 1$ and that $b$ is small, you can probably use the binomial expansion to try and "simplify" the expression (although really we will just be providing a low order approximation).

Comment: $$M=(1-b)^{N}+(N-4)(1-b)^{N-1} b \sum^{N}_{i=1} 2^{2i-2} \Delta^2 (1-b)^{N-1}b-(1-2b)^2$$

$$=(1-b)^{N}+(N-4)(1-b)^{N-1} b \Delta^2 (1-b)^{N-1}b\cdot 2^{-2}\sum^{N}_{i=1} 4^i -(1-2b)^2$$

Now, $\sum^{N}_{i=1} 4^i=\frac{4(4^N-1)}{4-1}$

Comment: It's not clear to me how this is related to linear algebra, so I removed the tag.